# Integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^4 + 1)}{x^2 +1}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x^4 + 1)}{x^2 + 1}dx$$
I tried Feynman's technique but got the wrong answer. I also tried by factoring $x^4+1$ as $(x^2+i)(x^2-i)$
where $i=\sqrt{-1}.$

Comment: This is a duplicate, almost certainly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. I agree with @FShrike, but if you know the residue theorem here's a hint: write the integral as$$2\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\ln(x+e^{i\pi/4})(x+e^{3i\pi/4})}{x^2+1}dx$$then use a semicircular contour in the upper half-plane. You should get $2\pi\ln(2+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: thx but is there any other way to integrate without using contour integration as i havent properly studied it